# How can I get PDFpreview to work?

Tags: 7, files

My site is on a wamp server.

I am trying to get my PDFs to show up as a thumbnail on my drupal 7 site. I have installed Imagemagick on my computer, i couldn't ever get it installed on my wamp (there was documentation that I found to that showed how to install php_imagick.dll onto my WAMP, but it was 3 years old and outdated), but it seems to work still.

I also have the PDFPreview module installed and configured (I ahve already gone to the configure page and saved), I have a file field set up to display with PDFPreview, but when I add pdfs to that field the preview is never made and I get this error from imagemagick

> Debug: ImageMagick error:
>   convert.exe: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "-sOutputFile=C:/Windows/TEMP/magick-9444Bo7mqLVmy-3f%d" "-fC:/Windows/TEMP/magick-9444h3BNhyb-tcOP" "-fC:/Windows/TEMP/magick-9444N2vudAzMQqXY"' (The system cannot find the file specified.) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/480.
>   convert.exe: PDFDelegateFailed`The system cannot find the file specified.' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/797.
>   convert.exe: no images defined `C:\wamp\www\MYSITE\sites\default\files\pdfpreview/24-Human Immunodeficiency Virus in Adults Testing algorithm 4-23-15.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
>   in _imagemagick_convert_exec() (line 500 of C:\wamp\www\MYSITE\sites\all\modules\imagemagick\imagemagick.module).

Has anyone had this error and been able to fix it?

If so how?